# Can't filter by alias after CASE-WHEN. Column doesn't exist

Tags: postgresql-9.5

column **data** has type **jsonb**

Here query that filter by phone number:

```
SELECT id, data,
CASE states->0->>'id'
    WHEN 'order.completed' THEN 'completed'
    ELSE 'progress'
    END AS order_state
FROM myTable
WHERE  data->'contacts'->'customer'->>'phone' LIKE '%123456%'
```

Nice. It's work fine.

But now I want also to filter by alias **order_state**.

I try this:

```
SELECT id, data,
CASE states->0->>'id'
    WHEN 'order.completed' THEN 'completed'
    ELSE 'progress'
    END AS order_state
FROM myTable
WHERE  data->'contacts'->'customer'->>'phone' LIKE '%123456%' AND order_state = 'progress'
```

But I get error:

```
ERROR:  column "order_state" does not exist
LINE 7: ...s'->'customer'->>'phone' LIKE '%123456%' AND order_stat...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your where condition has to be on the base value.

```
... WHERE ... AND states->0->>'id' <> 'order.completed';
```

which makes the CASE selection meaningless.